# Is there a way to get all YAML keys and do a different task for each of them?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, yaml

I've got this code so far

```
            Set<String> key = cfg.getKeys(false);
```

cfg = the YAML file

I would like to do something that can get all the keys and then i can use them individually

Example:

I have an YAML file with strings 1 , 2 , 3 , 4

And when i hover them in the game for example it shows a text "This is The number.. "

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Snake yaml](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.yaml/snakeyaml/1.29/bundle).

Add there dependency in your project

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
  <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
  <version>1.29</version>
  <type>bundle</type>
</dependency>
```

Pass the yaml file path and get all the keys

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("<your_yaml_file_path>"));

Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
Map<String, Object> data = yaml.load(inputStream);
Set<String> keys = data.keySet();
```